# Getting 'nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded' Winehq error while running .exe file on my linux VM

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, wine, linux-device-driver

I Installed Winehq stable release version 5.0 and on my Linux VM(Ubuntu 18.04) tried to run .exe file . I keep getting following errors.

0009:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded. 0009:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly.

I checked previous posts but there are fixes for Ubuntu 16.0 and not 18.04. Can someone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to install an earlier version - like 4.21? That might work for you. I have this problem but on bare metal, with all wine versions 5.0 and up. The wine bug report is here, and so far no reason why it happens and no fix: https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48647

Comment: What's funny is I'm getting this issue across every wine version from 6.0 to 9.0-staging-tkg, and have yet to find a fix, but the latest version that works for me is 5.6.5-tkg, and obviously DXVK isn't usable in that version... What's even weirder is 6.0 to 8.20-staging used to work until I changed my GPU configuration (removed my second GPU for better performance on the first GPU (first slot now uses 16 lanes instead of only 8))... So yeah, I'm stumped, because it should work just fine with nvidia on xorg...